# web2py sqlform grid row buttons

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, view, grid, web2py

I have problems with customizing SQLForm.grid row buttons. Right now I can only see text for view, edit and delete. How to include icons or bootstrap 3 icons?

any ideas?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grid takes a `ui` argument that defaults to "web2py", which adds Bootstrap 2 (and in the latest release, Bootstrap 3) icons and classes. You can also set `ui='jquery-ui'` if using Jquery UI. Otherwise, the `ui` argument can be a dictionary specifying classes for various elements -- the default dictionary in the current release is:

```
ui = dict(widget='',
          header='',
          content='',
          default='',
          cornerall='',
          cornertop='',
          cornerbottom='',
          button='button btn btn-default',
          buttontext='buttontext button',
          buttonadd='icon plus icon-plus glyphicon glyphicon-plus',
          buttonback='icon leftarrow icon-arrow-left glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left',
          buttonexport='icon downarrow icon-download glyphicon glyphicon-download',
          buttondelete='icon trash icon-trash glyphicon glyphicon-trash',
          buttonedit='icon pen icon-pencil glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-pencil',
          buttontable='icon rightarrow icon-arrow-right glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right',
          buttonview='icon magnifier icon-zoom-in glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-zoom-in',
          )
```

If using Bootstrap 3, upgrade to the latest release of web2py, or specify a custom dictionary as above.